# "ORA-24344: success with compilation error"

Tags: plsql

i just started with pl/sql and found this error. can someone tell what the problem is.

```
create or replace procedure findmin(x in number, y in number, z out 
number)
is
begin
if x<y then z:= x;
else z:=y;
end if;
end;


set serveroutput on;
declare
a number;
b number;
c number;
begin
a:=23;
b:=46;
findmin(a, b, c);
dbms_output.put_line('minimum of the 2 numbers is' || c);
end;
```

Comment: Does `show error` give you any more details?

Comment: Your code seems OK, try to recompile and give us more content of the error from the compiler.

Comment: The first block of code is running properly and the procedure gets created. when i run the second block of code it says
 "ORA-00922: missing or invalid option".
when i try to check the error using "select * from user_errors", it says "no data found".

Comment: @HarshVardhan Check out my answer. Try and let me know incase u face same issue.

Comment: I got the ans. I just needed to remove "set serveroutput on". I was using oracle apex. And thank you for ur help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `NO` error. Might be you re not executing it correctly.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE findmin(
  2                                      x IN NUMBER,
  3                                      y IN NUMBER,
  4                                      z OUT NUMBER)
  5  IS
  6  BEGIN
  7    
  8    IF x<y THEN
  9      z:= x;
 10    
 11    ELSE
 12      z:=y;
 13    
 14    END IF;
 15  
 16  END;
 17  
 18  /

Procedure created.

SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> DECLARE
  2    a NUMBER;
  3    b NUMBER;
  4    c NUMBER;
  5  BEGIN
  6    a:=23;
  7    b:=46;
  8    findmin(a, b, c);
  9    dbms_output.put_line('minimum of the 2 numbers is ' || c);
 10  
 11  END;
 12  /
minimum of the 2 numbers is 23

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: I am using oracle apex. the first block of code runs properly and shows procedure created. its the second block of code that is not getting executed. It says "ORA-00922: missing or invalid option"

Comment: @HarshVardhan If you are using APEX then why are you writing `set serveroutput on;` This statement is explicitly for `SQL` prompts. remove that and try.

Comment: thank you. it worked by removing "set serveroutput on". but can u tell me why that statement is not needed in oracle apex?

Comment: @HarshVardhan `SERVEROUTPUT` setting controls whether `SQL*Plus` prints the output generated by the `DBMS_OUTPUT` package from `PL/SQL` procedures. Its only supported while using `SQL` assistant. It desnot support apex.